# "Non-zero version length. Versions aren't supported" after zeoserver restart

Tags: zodb, plone-4.x

i try to restart zeoserver and get "Non-zero version length. Versions aren't supported".

$> bin/zeoserver fg

```
 /opt/Plone-4.2/zeocluster/parts/zeoserver/bin/runzeo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 405, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 402, in main
    s.main()
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 158, in main
    self.open_storages()
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 207, in open_storages
    self.storages[opener.name] = opener.open()
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/config.py", line 177, in open
    return FileStorage(config.path, **options)
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py", line 185, in __init__
    read_only=read_only,
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py", line 1554, in read_index
    h = fmt._read_data_header(pos)
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/FileStorage/format.py", line 150, in _read_data_header
    h = DataHeaderFromString(s)
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/FileStorage/format.py", line 236, in DataHeaderFromString
    return DataHeader(*struct.unpack(DATA_HDR, s))
  File "/opt/Plone-4.2/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/FileStorage/format.py", line 246, in __init__
    "Non-zero version length. Versions aren't supported.")
ValueError: Non-zero version length. Versions aren't supported.
```

in zeoserver.log i have:

```
2016-05-25T09:58:17 (22099) created PID file '/opt/Plone-4.2/zeocluster/var/zeoserver/zeoserver.pid'

2016-05-25T09:58:17 (22099) opening storage '1' using FileStorage

2016-05-25T09:59:27 (22099) removed PID file '/opt/Plone-4.2/zeocluster/var/zeoserver/zeoserver.pid'
```

All tries to "google" references to the fresh migration. But in my case it is a production server. There were no migrations, no updates, nothing.
14 days ago i had complete server restart from hoster side - no problem.
Zeoserver started without any problems. Today:
- bin/plonectl stop - allright. No problems or errors.
- bin/zeoserver start - "ValueError: Non-zero version length. Versions aren't supported."
I don't understand the problems root. So i can't solve this.

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

My experience with this type of situation points to a broken Data.fs, in most of the cases. You can fix it with the fsrecover.py script from the ZODB egg.